# Why does the decorrelated query not produce expected result?

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I am trying to decorrelate this correlated query:

```
select c1.c_name
    from customer c1
    where c1.c_mktsegment = 'AUTOMOBILE' or c1.c_acctbal >
    (select avg(c2.c_acctbal)
        from customer c2
        where c2.c_mktsegment = c1.c_mktsegment
    );
```

My solution is this:

```
select c1.c_name from customer c1, 
(select c_mktsegment, avg(c_acctbal) as m from customer group by c_mktsegment) c2 
where 
c1.c_mktsegment = 'AUTOMOBILE' or 
(c1.c_acctbal > c2.m and c1.c_mktsegment=c2.c_mktsegment);
```

But the problem I have is, I am getting multiple copy for the same `c_name`. I am not sure where I am doing wrong.

[Here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/sample-data-tpch.html#database-entities-relationships-and-characteristics) is the dataset schema.

Comment: Your where clause should be `c1.c_mktsegment=c2.c_mktsegment AND (c1.c_mktsegment = 'AUTOMOBILE' OR c1.c_acctbal > c2.m)`. You should also learn to use `JOIN`, it replaced implicit joins with `,` in 1992; I'm pretty sure being obselete for nearly ***three decades*** is long enough to stop using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make those queries equivalent you need to use the join condition `c1.c_mktsegment=c2.c_mktsegment` for every row. By making it part of the `OR`, you are joining every row of `c1` where `c1.c_mktsegment = 'AUTOMOBILE'` to every row of `c2` regardless of what c2.c_mkrsegment is.

I believe this is what you want:

```
select c1.c_name from customer c1, 
(select c_mktsegment, avg(c_acctbal) as m from customer group by c_mktsegment) c2 
where 
c1.c_mktsegment=c2.c_mktsegment
AND
(c1.c_mktsegment = 'AUTOMOBILE' OR c1.c_acctbal > c2.m)
```

The problem would likely be more clear if you used the better `inner join` syntax:

```
select c1.c_name from customer c1 INNER JOIN
(select c_mktsegment, avg(c_acctbal) as m from customer group by c_mktsegment) c2 
 ON c1.c_mktsegment=c2.c_mktsegment
WHERE
c1.c_mktsegment = 'AUTOMOBILE' OR c1.c_acctbal > c2.m
```

Comment: Thanks. your solution works perfectly. However I am confused about the statement you made - By making it part of the OR, you are joining every row of c1 to every row of c2 where c_mktsegment = 'AUTOMOBILE'. Here in c2, there are 5 rows, but in only 1 of them c_mktsegment = 'AUTOMOBILE', then why I get 5 copies?

Comment: @ahsanul If you have a row in c1 where c_mktsegment = 'AUTOMOBILE', it will join to every row of c2 in your original query. It doesn't matter what c2's c_mktsegment is.

Comment: I've improved my wording now.

Comment: It makes perfect sense now.